# Avoid error on extending an LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, inheritance

How the following error can be avoided

> $A.getCallback() [TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a
> constructor or null] Failing descriptor:" {ltng:outApp}

?

The base component

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
export default class DisplaysError extends LightningElement {
    error;

    displayError(err) {
        this.error = err;
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                'variant': 'error',
                "title": "Error",
                "message": err
            })
        );
    }
}
```

The descendant component

```
import { track } from 'lwc';
import { DisplaysError } from 'c/displaysError';
import action from '@salesforce/apex/Controller.action'
export default class Settings extends DisplaysError {

    @track record;
    connectedCallback() {
        action().then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            this.record = result;
            
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            this.displayError(error);
        }).finally(() => {
        })
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The braces around `DisplaysError` should be removed

```
import { track } from 'lwc';
import DisplaysError from 'c/displaysError';
import action from '@salesforce/apex/Controller.action'
export default class Settings extends DisplaysError {

    @track record;
    connectedCallback() {
        action().then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            this.record = result;
            
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            this.displayError(error);
        }).finally(() => {
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, i was also doing same mistake of braces around class name.